# IPython Notebook Sympy Math Rendering

Tags: sympy, jupyter-notebook

I have just started with using IPython Notebook and have been fascinated by its power. I have been using a few examples available on the net to get started with. I was following this tutorial: http://nbviewer.ipython.org/url/finiterank.com/cuadernos/suavesylocas.ipynb but the maths output is not getting rendered as expected. Below is the my code and the output:

```
In [30]:

%load_ext sympyprinting
%pylab inline

from __future__ import division
import sympy as sym
from sympy import *

init_printing()

x,y,z=symbols("x y z")
k,m,n=symbols("k m n", integer=True)

The sympyprinting extension is already loaded. To reload it, use:
  %reload_ext sympyprinting

Welcome to pylab, a matplotlib-based Python environment [backend: module://IPython.kernel.zmq.pylab.backend_inline].
For more information, type 'help(pylab)'.

In [31]:

t = sin(2*pi*x*(k**2))/ (4*(pi**2)*(k**5)) + (x**2) / (2*k)
t
Out[31]:
  2      ⎛     2  ⎞
 x    sin⎝2⋅π⋅k ⋅x⎠
─── + ─────────────
2⋅k         2  5   
         4⋅π ⋅k
```

I have tried other examples also, and they are also not getting rendered properly. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: There seem to be as many ways as versions*users. There is also A Correct Way(TM) that I would also like to know.

Comment: What happens if you remove the `init_printing` and/or `pylab` lines?

Comment: @asmeurer: No change. Still the same output

Comment: Does it work if you use `%load_ext sympy.interactive.ipythonprinting`? You need SymPy 0.7.2.

Comment: @asmeurer: I have Sympy 0.7.2 but it is saying: Object `sympy.interactive.ipythonprinting` not found.

Comment: What version of IPython are you using?

Comment: IPython Version: 1.0.dev9051
Build: 660

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I had the same problem. Try

```
from sympy.interactive import printing
printing.init_printing(use_latex=True)
```

instead of

```
%load_ext sympyprinting
```

I am using sympy 0.7.2

Comment: Works like a charm with sympy 1.0 and IPython 5.4.1. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I recently had the same problem, and I'm using Linux Crunchbang, which is a derivative of Redhat I think. Originally I installed sympy using

```
pip install sympy
```

However, this led to the above problem as described. So then I went to the sympy webpage and cloned the git repository to a folder. Then it can be installed (once in the local folder) by using

```
python setup.py install
```

After that everything worked fine, so I think it had something to do with the version used. For the record, the commands I used to initialize the printing in python were

```
import sympy
sympy.init_printing()
```

Answer (score 2):

Import:

```
from sympy import *
init_printing()
```

Example:

```
x = symbols('x')
a = Integral(cos(x)*exp(x), x)
Eq(a, a.doit())
```

Output:

[image: Eq(Integral(exp(x)*cos(x), x), exp(x)*sin(x)/2 + exp(x)*cos(x)/2)]