# How to display symbolic equation using jupyter notebook?

Tags: latex, ipython, sympy, jupyter-notebook

I used to use ipython notebook for displaying equations while using simpy module. As can be seen from the figure below it is neat and elegant.

[image: ipython notebook equation display]

It seems I have made some updates and I no more have ipython notebook; every time I run it, it switches back to Jupyter (I guess that is a new name after 4). Unfortunately, printing equation doesn't work as it used to yet I can type latex as Markdown text(see figure below). Am I missing something?

[image: jupyter notebook equation display]

Comment: see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16152040/ipython-notebook-sympy-math-rendering

Comment: There was a wrong attachment sorry for that. I am actually using `from sympy.interactive import printing
printing.init_printing(use_latex=True)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So finally it is working thanks to [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/IPython/comments/3rg9lh/help_latex_eq_rendering_not_working_in_jupyter/) reddit post. I just needed to update sympy module.

```
pip install -U sympy
```

Comment: Yep, there is a bug in Jupyter printing in SymPy version 0.7.6. The patch fix 0.7.6.1 or the newest version (1.0) have fixed this bug.